# How to override\change HttpSession timeout in OC4J 10g (10.1.3.5.0)

Tags: session, session-timeout, httpsession, oc4j

In my WAR's **web.xml**, I added the following XML tags:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Although I've done that, the session doesn't timeout after 1 minute. I registered a HttpSessionListener to monitor the session creation\destruction:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.listener.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

...and only the session-creation indicator method is called when a session is created, but the session-destruction method isn't called after one minute as expected, yet its called after **20 minutes** though, which is the **default** timeout duration in OC4J.

How can I change this default behavior ?!

Comment: We set ours to 60 that way and it seems to work.  Presumably you rebuilt and redeployed the app after modifying the web.xml; might want to confirm that all went as expected.

Comment: I've confirmed that the timeout I specified is recognized by OC4J by checking the value in the application's administration tab. It shows 60 seconds, but the session always times-out after 20 minutes !